# HTTPS SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, https, ssh-tunnel

Ok so I have a web server, lets call it Server A, which is providing a service via HTTPS. And I have an SSH gateway server, lets call it Server B.

Due to firewall rules I cannot access Server A's web service from my desktop linux computer. Therefore to view the web service I must SSH with X Forwarding to Server B and run firefox over the SSH tunnel. Server B can access Server A's web service and so it works.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to create an SSH tunnel between my PC and Server B which would allow me to access the service on Server A using my desktop web browser rather than running firefox over the SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

`ssh -L 8443:serverA:443 -Nf [user@]<serverB>`

This will let you point your desktop browser at port 8443 and send it to port 443 (the HTTPS port) on your server A. The `-Nf` will background the session and exit immediately back to your desktop, not establishing an actual shell session to server B.

Comment: You could also go directly to server A: `ssh -L 8443:localhost:443 -Nf [user@]<serverA>`

Comment: Isnt HTTPS port 443?

Comment: Right... feeling stupid now...  sorry. Will make edits. I honestly don't know where I got 437 from...

Comment: I cannot go directly to Server A due to firewall restrictions. And I'm afraid the above doesn't work for me I get this error message `channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`. I assume Server B has `AllowTCPForwarding` disabled.

Comment: Which machine do you run this command on?  PC?  serverA?

Comment: @krupan from the PC.

Comment: I get several errors when trying to use these tunnels. When trying to connect to my router remotely, 400 Bad Request. If I try to connect to public servers, like Google or www.eldiario.es, something mess up and I get 404 or unknown domain... (I guess this is because of virtual names for one web server serving multiple domains).

Comment: This has always confused me: `ssh -L 8443:serverA:443 -Nf [user@]<serverB>` actually forwards 8443 on localhost to serverA:443 via serverB as “SSH jump server”. I always find it counterintuitive...

Comment: So I guess it is correct to point the browser to 'localhost:8443' through http? Gives me a "Bad request. You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.". But using https is not an option either. Or is it?

Answer (score 17):

You dont even require `SSH Tunneling` to access the `web service` in `Server A`. You can use `Dynamic Port Forwarding`

```
ssh -N -D 9000 user@server_b
```

and configure your web browser to use SOCKS proxy host `127.0.0.1` and port `9000`

Comment: He'll likely have to create some proxy exceptions, since using the proxy for everything won't let him get to resources that server B can't get to. Depending on the complexity of his work network, trying to use a proxy might be more effort than it's worth.

Comment: I do agree John. I just want to point that it is doable with `Dynamic Port Forwarding` too :)

Comment: Which machine do you run this command on? PC? serverA?

Comment: Tried it.  Run the command on the PC