# Forward port to serveur via dedicated machine

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, redirection

I have a mailserver M answering port 587 but only for a given authorized machine A. From my regular machine R, I want to contact M on 587 via A. I have full control over A and R, but but M.

Can I setup SSH tunnels and port forwarding for that?

I've read several posts describing SSH port forwarding, but it seems the usual examples don't discuss such a use case. E.g., [this link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/) discusses Local Port Forwarding and Remote Port Forwarding, but neither would seem to do the trick in this situation.

I can setup e.g. Local Port Forwarding such that port 587 on R in redirected to some port on A, say 5877, but how would I setup A such that incoming traffic on port 5877 is redirected to port 587 on M?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTPS SSH Tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/581530/https-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: I guess so! I'll try. Thanks @GeraldSchneider!